# WordPress Multisite - how to import ALL admins' emails into MailChimp?

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

The setup is pretty straightforward:

- WordPress Multisite Network
- 100+ sub-blogs already running on the network
- New sub-blogs being created, even more expected on a daily basis

I have yet to figure out the best way to ***automatically*** import the email address of **all** the admins of the sub-blogs into MailChimp. As I was outlining above, the network is composed of more than 100 sub-blogs, and while I could technically just export their admins' emails into a CSV file, in order to import them into MailChimp, I don't like this half-baked approach. Especially considering that I would need to be aware and manually handle the admin's email of **each and every** newly-created sub-blog on the network.

I don't have much experience with MailChimp, but there's someone else who's in charge of building and handling the email marketing campaigns. I only need to provide them with a bulletproof solution to the problem above.

Comment: If you can export a CSV file, that sounds like it should be something that you should be able to automate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the first export through CSV. Then, whenever someone signs up for a new blog post, just call the MailChimp API from your code to subscribe them:

> To add someone to your list, send a POST request to the List Members endpoint: `/3.0/lists/9e67587f52/members/`. The request body should be a JSON object that has the member information you want to add, with status and any other required list fields.
>
> ```
> {
>     "email_address": "urist.mcvankab@freddiesjokes.com",
>     "status": "subscribed",
>     "merge_fields": {
>         "FNAME": "Urist",
>         "LNAME": "McVankab"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> *[MailChimp API Documentation](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/)*